# Disable all SQLServer engines except LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I am using LocalDB for DB testing but my dev PC seems to have SQLServer 2005, 2008 and 2012 installed/running - I am not sure exactly which are running as there are so many services and I have 3 versions of SQLServer Configuration Manager installed!

I want to disable all DB engines other than LocalDB and am wondering if I just turn all the SQLServer services to off, start-mode = manual, this will achieve my aim... or will also turn off LocalDB?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that *localdb* is a database that is hosted on one of the instances you're running on your machine.  If you know the instance name (e.g. SQLExpress, SYSARCH, SYSARCH1, or the default [and therefore unnamed] instance) you connect to when working with localdb, yes, you can set the other database **instances** to either manual start or disabled so they will not auto-start after a reboot.  Another approach is to use the [services.msc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755249.aspx) snap-in, but know that this will list all services on the machine instead of only the SQL Server services.

Comment: I've tried turning them all off and confirmed no instance of SQLServer.exe was running. Yet when I connect to LocalDB through VS it still works, which is good enough for me!

Comment: You likely have a stored connection within your VS project which is configured for a separate server.  Glad you got it sorted, though I suspect at some point in the future you'll need to change it for a proper deployment.